# Cant delete or rename folder or excel file after it opens

Tags: windows, excel

How to find what is blocking file or folder from being deleted or renamed?

After i open my Excel file and when close it i cant delete or rename nor folder nor this excel file.

Unlocker 1.9.2 do not find locking decriptor.

There are any ways to unblock file or folder or find which program is using it?

I cant restart PC after each time i opening the file.

[image]

I just installed Proccess Explorer and search for my folder name

it shows me what fonts which i attach on workbook open is locked by System

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AddFontResource ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AGENCYR.TTF"
    AddFontResource ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AGENCYB.TTF"

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    RemoveFontResource ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AGENCYR.TTF"
    RemoveFontResource ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AGENCYB.TTF"
End Sub
```

And my folder is locked by explorer.exe

So how to unblock thoose decriptor on Excel closing?

Comment: No, all files and folders in c:\

Comment: Did you open task manager to see if excel is still running?

Comment: Excel is not running